# Symbol for membership of one and only

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Is there a symbol that states $a$ is **only** a member of $A$ as in the image?

[image]

I can use ($a \in A - B$) or ($a \in A$ and $ a \notin B $). But, I need the shortest possible mathematical description for this if available. Since I use longer names for sets such as `UniqueGeometryA` and `UniqueGeometryB`, the mathematical phrases that I use become longer.

Comment: What do you mean by "I use long words for $A$ and $B$..."

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I have revised the question.

Comment: How can you expect to write that $x$ belongs to one set but not the other without even writing the names of the sets in question? $a\in A-B$ only uses two exra symbols. I would suggest to adopt shorter names for your sets.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I have just two sets and if possible I want to use one of them for example when stating $a$ is just a member of set `UniqueGeometryA`. With shorter names, it is not possible to describe what I mean in that case. If there is no any symbol for that, I have to use `a ∈ UniqueGeometryA − UniqueGeometryB` or `a ∈ UniqueGeometryA  and a ∉ UniqueGeometryB`.

Comment: I am afraid I am not aware of more concise notation for what you want to say. Let us wait for someone else to answer your question.

Comment: I would suggest just naming the sets as you have done here: call one $A$ and the other $B$ and say $a\in A\setminus B$.  You can just make the names "local" if you want (writing, e.g., for $A=$ "UniqueGeometryA" and $B=$ "UniqueGeometryB", $a\in A\setminus B$).  I don't know of any simpler means of writing this since you will always have to specify which sets you're looking at.  Otherwise, how will I know whether you mean $a\in A$ but not $B$ vs. $a\in A$ but not $B$, $C$, $D$, nor $E$?